# Completeness in the Riemann sphere

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

My professor showed us that the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a complete metric space, and moreover if we took the one-point compactification of the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2\cup\{\infty\}$ then the result will not be a complete metric space. I was thinking about this statement and how I could prove it. I thought first about the metric which induces the same topology as the one already defined on the one-point compactification. I found this metric:

$$d(z,z')=\frac{ 2\|z-z'\| }{\sqrt{ \left( 1+ \|z\|^2 \right) } \sqrt{\left( 1+ \|z'\|^2 \right)}}$$

$$d(\infty,z)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\|z\|^2}}$$

$$d(\infty,\infty) = 0$$

I tried to think about a Cauchy sequence that does not converge with this metric, but failed.

Comment: The one-point compactification of a locally compact (Hausdorff) space is compact, hence if it is metrisable, complete with respect to every metric inducing the topology. The one-point compactifications of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are metrisable.

Comment: Your professor may have meant that you cannot extend a metric with respect to which $\mathbb{R}^2$ is complete to a metric on the one-point compactification so that the extension induces the topology.

Comment: Another possibility for what your professor may have meant is that if you take a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty\}$ which induces the one-point-compactification topology, and if you restrict that metric to $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the result cannot possibly be complete. The reason is: there is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which, when included into $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty\}$, will converge to $\infty$. That sequence is thus a Cauchy sequence. But it cannot converge in $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself.

Comment: @DanielFischer - the one-point compatification of $\Bbb R^n$ is $S^n$. The metric on $S^n$ inherited from $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ generates the topology of $S^n$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes. And of course a subspace of $S^n$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ isn't complete in that metric.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Obviously not. My apologies.